# Dynamic Celery Scheduling

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

Using Django & Celery is it possible to add/modify the scheduler dynamically from code and have it update in real time.

I noticed the `/admin/djcelery/periodictask/add/` option in the admin panel to add periodic tasks but how can this be done from my Django views?

Ideally I'd be able to add multiple period tasks with the same task but different arguments

Answer (score 0):

Just create a periodictask object.

```
from djcelery.models import PeriodicTask 
PeriodicTask.objects.create(...)
```

You may have problems because you may need to restart celerybeat.. to reload all periodic tasks.